# className not found/undefined after function

Tags: javascript, classname

I have this function:

```
  var save = document.getElementById('savethis'+this.parentNode.childNodes[1].id);
    save.addEventListener('click', savethis.bind(this), false);

function savethis() {
  this.removeEventListener('click', edit);
  var a = this.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].id;
  console.log(a);
  var b = document.getElementById(a);
  console.log(document.getElementById(a).id.replace('minedit',''));
  console.log(b.value);
  this.innerHTML = b.value;
  this.parentNode.cells[4].className = 'text-center min-edit';


  setTimeout(function() {this.addEventListener('click',edit);},1);
}
```

In another function:

```
var minedit = document.getElementsByClassName('min-edit');
 for (var m=0;m<minedit.length;m++){
    minedit[m].addEventListener('click', edit);
 }

function edit(){

    var avalue = this.innerHTML;
console.log(avalue);
    if (this.className.indexOf('input-open')>=0){

}

else {
    this.className += ' input-open';
    var content = '';
    content += '<div class="input-group editable-input"><input type="text" id="minedit'+this.parentNode.childNodes[1].id+'" value="'+parseFloat(avalue).toFixed(2)+'" class="form-control"><span class="input-group-addon editable-input" id="savethis'+this.parentNode.childNodes[1].id+'"><i class="ion-android-done" ></i></span><span class="input-group-addon editable-input"><i class="ion-android-close" id="close"></i></span></span></div>';
    this.innerHTML = content;


    valuenow = document.getElementById('minedit'+this.parentNode.childNodes[1].id).value;
    id = document.getElementById('minedit'+this.parentNode.childNodes[1].id).id;
 var save = document.getElementById('savethis'+this.parentNode.childNodes[1].id);
    save.addEventListener('click', savethis.bind(this), false);


}

}
function savethis() {
  this.removeEventListener('click', edit);
    var a = this.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].id;
    var b = document.getElementById(a);
    this.innerHTML = b.value;
    this.parentNode.cells[4].className = 'text-center min-edit';
    setTimeout(function() {this.addEventListener('click',edit);},1);
}
```

As you can see in the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/e207wmmo/1/), the opening and closing of the input box works on the first click, but on the second click I get an error saying

```
TypeError: this.className is undefined
```

pointing to this line:

```
 if (this.className.indexOf('input-open')>=0){
```

I totally don't get why className could possibly be undefined, as I define it's name within the savethis function.

Can someone explain and help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scope is wrong

```
setTimeout(function() {this.addEventListener('click',edit);},1);
```

`this` is the document when this runs, not the element.

```
var that = this;
setTimeout(function() {that.addEventListener('click',edit);},1);
```

or use bind() with modern browsers

```
setTimeout( (function() {this.addEventListener('click',edit);}).bind(this),1);
```